# Grails domain class event listner in service level

Tags: events, grails

I want to interrupt some specific grails domain class events(read,write,delete,update).Is there any hibernate eventlistner available for grails domain classes.So that all the calls will go through that eventslistner.I tried following def beforeLoad={}, def beforeInsert={} ,etc ..Other than that is there any other way something can be done in service level?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Providing an example will definitely help us understand the problem. Cheers.

Comment: I want to do some authorization. If authorization fails wants throw exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to implement an authentication-mechanism is by using [Grails Filters](http://www.grails.org/Filters) (follow the link for a more advanced example) e.g.

```
class SecurityFilters {
   def filters = {

       loginCheck(controller:'*', action:'*') {

          before = {
             if(!session.user && !actionName.equals('login')) { 
                redirect(action:'login') return false } 
             }
          } 
       } 
    }
 }
```

If you need more advanced authentication tooling try:

- [Spring Security Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/acegi)
- [Stark Security Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/stark-security)
- [Apache Shiro Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/shiro)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to secure domain objects read about [Secure Objects](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&as_q=secure+object&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&num=10&lr=&as_filetype=&ft=i&as_sitesearch=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.springsource.org%2Fspring-security%2Fsite%2Fdocs%2F3.0.x%2Freference&as_qdr=all&as_rights=&as_occt=any&cr=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&safe=images) in the [Spring Security's](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html) manual. There is also the wonderful [Grails Acegi Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/acegi).

Cheers!